# Как сохранить разные типы данных в один plist?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

У меня код сохраняет переменную:

```
-(NSString *)getFilePath
{
    NSArray *myAllPass = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    return [[myAllPass objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"saved.plist"];

}

-(void)saveData;
{
        NSMutableDictionary *myPlistData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[self getFilePath]];
        if (myPlistData == nil) {
            myPlistData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        }
        [myPlistData setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:int] forKey:@"int_key"];
  [myPlistData writeToFile:[self getFilePath] atomically:YES];
 }
```

к неме нужно прикрутить код сохранения значений с лейблов

```
NSArray *LabelValue = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:[display_lab1 text], [display_lab2 text],  nil];
```

[LabelValue writeToFile:[self getFilePath] atomically:YES];

но вместе они не работают:
предпологаю что они перезаписывают один другого, и чтоб этого избежать нужно либо каждому присвоить ключ, либо использовать другой файл например:saved2.plist, но этого делать не хочеться, подскажите как в один plist записать разные типы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, Вы попросту перезаписываете файл. Записывайте разные данные по разным ключам. У вас же

```
[myPlistData setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:int] forKey:@"int_key"];
```

записывается по ключу `int_key`. Точно таким же образом добавьте в `myPlistData` массив по какому-то уникальному ключу. Например:

```
NSArray *LabelValue = @[ [display_lab1 text], [display_lab2 text] ];
[myPlistData setObject:LabelValue forKey:@"label_value"];
[myPlistData writeToFile:[self getFilePath] atomically:YES];
```

Ну и прочтите что-то про формат проперти листов и их маппинг на объекты и обратно.

Comment: Ок, загружать тогда как? 
я раньше использовал такую структуру 
NSArray *values1 = [[NSArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:[self getFilePath]];
display_lab1.text = [values1 objectAtIndex:0];
display_lab2.text = [values1 objectAtIndex:2];
но сейчас то с ключами))

Comment: NSMutableDictionary *myPlistData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[self getFilePath]];

    NSArray *LabelValue = [myPlistData objectForKey:@"label_value"];

Comment: Благодарю !!!

Answer (score 0):

Конечно перезаписывают, вы ведь дергаете writeToFile, а он перезаписывает файл, а не дописывает в него. Действительно нужно использовать ключи, но кроме этого еще надо для LabelValue читать файл старый файл и менять в нем значения по ключу (как вы делаете в saveData). Ну и просто в качестве совета - определить где-нибудь в начале ключи через const или #define, оно вас потом спасет от ошибок из-за опечаток, да и править если что будет проще

Comment: Спасибо,я так и думал)))
#define использовать пока не буду, не такая уж и большая программа))

Comment: Дело ваше, я просто однажды так долго ловил баг, потом оказалось что опечатался в ключе просто - писал по одному, а читал по другому, с тех пор всегда делаю их какими-нибудь константами